# Don't show a notification if currently inside of my app? Android GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I essentially only want a GCM notification to be put in the notification tray if the user is outside of my application. What is the easiest way to check if the user is currently inside of the application? Thanks in advance

Comment: The other question seems to be a duplicate, but the the answers will only work if: 1. "You are in an activity and not a receiver" 2. "You can tell if the application is running, but not necessarily in the foreground"

Comment: @GuyLeStack, see the second answer in the duplicate link.

Comment: The answer by Gadenkan would only seemingly tell you if the app is running. Not whether or not your app is running in the foreground or background. Correct?

Comment: _Then check with the first task(task in the foreground)_ --- the first task in the returned list is the foreground app. If that's yours, then you are in foreground, otherwise in background.

Comment: Gotcha. Will try that out. Thanks